# Command time out Error in Delphi ADO

Tags: delphi, ado, delphi-2010

I am executing a storedprocedure in Oracle With ADOStoredProcedure in  Delphi 2010. The procedure execution time is 2 minutes.I set Command timeout to 20 Seconds.

When I am Executing the procedure ,Error is not raising related to timeout & procedure is executing for 2 minutes. How to get error at 20th Second

I used Connection string

`'Provider=MSDAORA.1;Password=pthmu;User ID=pthmu;Data Source=orcl_300'`

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour of `ADO.CommandTimeout` is depending on *provider* and *data source* as stated in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678265%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Use the CommandTimeout property on a Connection object or Command
>   object to allow the cancellation of an Execute method call, due to
>   delays from network traffic or heavy server use. If the interval set
>   in the CommandTimeout property elapses before the command completes
>   execution, an error occurs and ADO cancels the command. If you set the
>   property to zero, ADO will wait indefinitely until the execution is
>   complete. **Make sure the provider and data source to which you are
>   writing code support the CommandTimeout functionality.**

**UPDATE**

[Connection Timeout and Query Timeout Not Supported with Microsoft Oracle ODBC Driver and OLE DB Provider](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;251248)

> After the query has been sent to the Oracle server, there is **no way to cancel the query** by using the Oracle OCI. In the case of the preceding connection timeout, you are canceling the request for the connection before it has been completed.